# secure my servers with iptables

Tags: iptables

I have 2 vps servers (debian 7 & 8) with a public IP address and I would like to protect them. I would like to have access only to SSH (public/private keys), openVPN, services that are requested from the servers  themselves, such as sending emails.

I have setup iptables:

```
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT  
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT  
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT  
iptables -F  
iptables -X  
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT  
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT  
iptables -P INPUT DROP  
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 22 -j ACCEPT  
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 1194 -j ACCEPT  
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
```

all services from the servers to the outside world must work, such asterisk registrations to trunks, email sending.
I would like to block all scanners and have my servers secure proof with iptables. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I would use `rsyslog` to setup iptables activity  into its own log files, not shared with `/var/log/syslog`.
before you get into systems that dynamically block scanners, get the basics right, i.e. do you have the ability to manually detect if you are being scanned?
If repeated port scanning becomes a problem - then I would suggest looking into using fail2ban to monitor your iptables log file and dynamically add iptables rules as necessary.
But I would first follow the logs of all sensitive systems and get a handle on what happening with your server and any abuses towards it, then use your common sense to focus your efforts on what is appropriate and most urgent.